# What are the possible outcomes when joining (inner, outer, left, right) the tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A has 10 records, table B has 100 rows. The relationship between A and B is 1:N. What are the possible outcomes when joining the tables? The possible answers answers are

1. 100 rows, using A INNER JOIN B
2. 10 records, using A LEFT JOIN B
3. 10 records, using A RIGHT JOIN B
4. 10 records, using A FULL OUTER JOIN B
5. 100 records, using A FULL OUTER JOIN B
6. Minimal number of output rows is 10
7. Maximal number of output rows is 1000

As a mathematician using my knowledge of matrices it seems the answer may be a) but I am not too sure, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is the full question with the data.

Comment: Correct statements: 1, 2, 5, 7, if I'm not mistaken. So what is the task actually? Shall you tick the correct statements and give an explanation?

Comment: 7 appears to be the only correct answer

Comment: "...The relationship between A and B is 1:N..." What does this even mean?

Comment: @Strawberry: The question is " What are the possible outcomes when joining the tables?" Why is #1 impossible for instance?

Comment: I'm with @Strawberry. #7 is the only correct one.

Comment: #1 can produce anywhere between 0 and 1000 rows.

Comment: @The Impaler: Correct. So it *is* possible to get 100 rows.

Comment: Yep, it's possible.

Comment: ...but by no means inevitable

Comment: … which is the difference between "possible outcomes" and "guaranteed outcomes". 100 rows for an inner join is a possible outcome. When asking "what are the possible outcomes when joining the tables", #1 is among them.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will ignore the sentence:

> The relationship between A and B is 1:N

since I don't really understand what that means. Here's my take:

```
#1 Wrong. Inner join can produce anywhere between 0 and 1000 rows.

#2 Wrong. Left join can produce anywhere between 10 and 1000 rows.

#3 Wrong. Right join can produce anywhere between 100 and 1000 rows.

#4 Wrong. Full outer join can produce anywhere between 100 and 1000 rows.

#5 Wrong. Full outer join can produce anywhere between 100 and 1000 rows.

#6 Wrong. Joins can produce anywhere between 0 and 1000 rows.

#7 Correct. Joins can produce anywhere between 0 and 1000 rows.
```

Comment: I don't agree with "wrong" and "correct". For #1 statement for instance that 100 is a possible result is "correct" for me. Your numbers are correct, however, except for "between 110 and 1000"; it's "between 100 and 1000".

Comment: Ah... 10A x 10B + 90B = 100.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think of 1 to many is pages in a book. So assume table A is a list of books [book 1], [book 2], ..., [book 10] and table B is a list of distinct pages of text in those books e.g., [book 1 | text on page 1 of book 1], [book 2 | text on page 1 of book 2], [book 2 | text on page 2 of book 2]. We'll keep table A constant and vary table B.

[1] and [5] would be possible if, for example, table B contained the first 10 pages of text for each book in table A, with each page in its own row.

[2] would be possible if, for example, table B contained the first page of text for each book in table A and the first 90 pages of text for book 11 (not in table A).

[3] and [4] would not be possible as the resulting table would have to be at least the size of table B.

[6] depends on the join operation. With an inner join, for example, if no records match (e.g., table B begins with pages from book 11 and goes from there), then the output could be 0.

[7] would not be possible given the parameter of 1 to many. 1000 would be possible iff every row in table A joined with every element in table B, but that would require a row of table B joining with multiple rows in table 1 (many to many).

Answer (score 0):

The Impaler has given you the correct number of rows the joins can result in.

I'd like to give my 5c on the 1:N relation.

We know such relations from, say, departments and employees. A department can have many employees; an employee only works in one department.

Maybe, just maybe, the person asking the question had joins on the foreign key in mind. In above example this would be some department ID. For every record in table B (employees) we would find exactly one record in table A (departments). And for every department we may find multiple employees. But then, 1:N is just short for either 1:{0,n} or 1:{1,n).

- 1:{0,n} means a department can have zero to many employees
- 1:{1,n) means a department can have one to many employees

Joins are not necessarily on the foreign key. Yes, we can say: list all employees with their departments (and hence join on the department ID, the foreign key). But we could also say show me all employees  whose main skill matches the main skill needed in a department and come out with all 1000 combinations (every employee could work in every department) or none (no employee actually has the skill to work in any department).

So it makes a big difference, whether the interviewer mentioned the 1:N relation for thinking of joins on the foreign key or not.

In the case that we always only join on the foreign key (the department ID in my example):

1. 100 rows, using A INNER JOIN B - Yes, we'll get exactly 100 rows, i.e. 100 employees, each with their department.
2. 10 records, using A LEFT JOIN B - No, we'll get at least the 100 rows as with an inner join. We may get departments too that have no employees, if 1:N means 1:{0,n}.
3. 10 records, using A RIGHT JOIN B - No, we'll get the same 100 rows as with an inner join
4. 10 records, using A FULL OUTER JOIN B - No, we'll get the same 100 or more rows as with A LEFT JOIN B
5. 100 records, using A FULL OUTER JOIN B - That's possible. We'll get the same 100 or more rows as with A LEFT JOIN B. So 100 rows is possible, but not guaranteed.
6. Minimal number of output rows is 10 - No, we'll get 100 to 109 rows (100, if all departments have employees, 109, if only one department has employees). Again it's the question what 1:N really means.
7. Maximal number of output rows is 1000 - No, with inner and outer joins on the foreign key we'll get 100 to 109 rows.